# How to interact with Chrome extension installation dialog in Selenium?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, automation

I am working on automating a Chrome extension installation using Selenium WebDriver. I know

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--load-extension=" + pluginDir);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

works fine. But I would like to do it other way by interacting with the dialog that appears shown below.

Currently, I am not able to interact with the dialog, no right click is allowed to see the web elements on the dialog.

[image]

How can I handle the dialog or can it be automated? What kind of dialog is that?

Comment: @rob-w could you answer my question to how is the dialog implemented but not how to work around.

Comment: That dialog is implemented in https://cs.chromium.org/file%3Aextension_install_prompt.cc. Chrome does not support a way to click on the dialog, so you can only use work-arounds (either mocking the installation, or dispatching GUI events; see linked question).

Comment: this makes more sense. Thanks